# If $A$ is a positive integer and $\gcd(pq,A)=1$ holds (where $p$ and $q$ are primes), does it follow that $\gcd(p,A)=1$ and $\gcd(q,A)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

My question here is pretty basic, so I apologize in advance if there is a simple answer.

**INITIAL QUESTION**

> If $A$ is a positive integer and $\gcd(pq,A)=1$ holds (where $p$ and $q$ are primes), does it follow that $\gcd(p,A)=1$ and $\gcd(q,A)=1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $A$ be a positive integer, and suppose that $\gcd(pq,A)=1$ holds (where $p$ and $q$ are primes).

Without loss of generality, suppose that $\gcd(p,A) > 1$.  Since $p$ is prime, then we consider two cases:

- Case 1: $A < p$

Since $p$ is prime, $A < p$ would imply that $\gcd(p,A) = 1$, contradicting our assumption.

- Case 2: $A \geq p$

Since $p$ is prime, and since $\gcd(p,A) > 1$, then $A \geq p$ implies that $\gcd(p,A)=p$, which further means that $p \mid A$.  This implies that we can write $A = pa$, for some positive integer $a$.  Thus, we obtain $$\gcd(pq,A)=\gcd(pq,pa)=p\cdot\gcd(q,a) \geq p \geq 2,$$ which contradicts $\gcd(pq,A)=1$.

**QED**

**FINAL QUESTION**

> Does the proof above generalize to a valid argument for the following proposition?

- If $B$ is a positive integer and $$C = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(C)}{p_i}$$ is squarefree such that $\gcd(B,C)=1$, does it follow that $\gcd(B,p_i)=1$ for each $i$, $1 \leq i \leq \omega(C)$?

Comment: an alternative definition of coprime  is a Bezout identity. You begin with $pqx + Ay=1.$    But then $p(qx) + Ay=1$    and $q(px) + Ay=1.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thank you for your comment.  So are you saying that Bezout's Identity directly proves
$$\gcd(pq,A) = 1 \implies \bigl(\gcd(p,A) = 1 \land \gcd(q,A) = 1\bigr)?$$
And that it seems the hypothesis that $p$ and $q$ are primes is not even needed in order for the proof to work?

Comment: yes.   you might look into why this is an equivalent definition; in one direction it is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, @WillJagy!  Now, I remember.  =)

Comment: For any $a,b,c$, a number that divides $b$ will also divide $bc$. Therefore $\gcd(a,b)$ necessarily divides $\gcd(a,bc)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, @eyeballfrog, for the insightful comment!  =)

Comment: By the linked dupe $(A,p)\mid (A,pq)=1\,$ so $(A,p)=1\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that any common divisor of $p$ and $A$ is also a common divisor of $pq$ and $A$. So $\gcd(pq,A)\ge \gcd(p,A) \ge 1$. But you're given that $\gcd(pq,A)=1$.

By the way $p$ and $q$ don't have to be primes for the result to hold.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).